Which area correctly reveals the variable cost, area under AVC also compelling

I know that the area $A$ under the MC producing at $q$ is the total variable cost, but rectangle area $B$ obtained by $AVC*q$ is also compelling, why do two different ways lead to two different variable costs?
Personally inclined to area $A$, but I have no idea what is wrong with argument area $B$
please help

That is because your figure is not drawn to scale. Take the following cost function:
\begin{align}
TC(q) = \underbrace{[(q-4)^3 +64]}_{VC(q)} + \underbrace{36\vphantom{q}}_{FC} 
\end{align}
where the $+64$ term is to ensure that $VC(0)=0$.
The associated cost curves are plotted below. By simple eyeballing, the green area under the MC is the same as the area of the purple rectangle. Of course, this can be verified analytically using the above equation.

